# Quicksort Algorithm--Ruby Implementation

Tags: ruby, algorithm, quicksort

Have been bashing my head in trying to debug my quicksort implementation and could use a new set of eyes. I'm following along Robert Sedgewick's Coursera Algorithms course and I have absolutely no idea what's wrong with the way I'm doing it (looks nearly identical to his java implementation). Any ideas? I know my partition method works since I've extensively stress-tested it (i.e if I submit low to be 0 and high as 2, then the array will be properly partitioned between those indices).

Also, I'm using quicksort as an in-place sort so that's why I'm not creating an auxiliary array.

```
def shuffle(arr)
  arr.each_index do |i|
    r = rand(0..i)
    arr[i], arr[r] = arr[r], arr[i]
  end
  arr
end

def partition!(arr,low, high)
  #debugger
  arr = shuffle(arr)
  i = low + 1 
  j = high
  while true 
    until arr[i] >= arr[low]
      break if i >= high
      i+=1
    end

    until arr[j] <= arr[low]
      j-=1
    end

    if i>=j 
      #done 
      arr[j], arr[low] = arr[low], arr[j]
      break 
    else 
      #swap and continue
      arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    end
  end 
end


def quicksort(arr, low = 0, high=arr.length-1)
  arr = shuffle(arr)
  quicksort!(arr, low, high)
end

def quicksort!(arr, low, high)
   #p "Quicksorting on low index #{low} and high index #{high}"
   return arr if (high <= low)
   j = partition!(arr, low, high)
   quicksort!(arr, low, j-1)
   quicksort!(arr, j+1, high)
end
```

Comment: Are you able to run this program? `quicksort!` method takes 4 arguments and you are calling it with 3 arguments.

Comment: sorry about that-- I accidentally copied over a version that I was debugging. Fixed it now.

Comment: Which array do you try to sort, which method do you call and do you get an unsorted array, or do you get an error?

Comment: maybe try this? - https://repl.it/ExHB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.

## Problems

#### #1

`partition` should return `j`. See the corresponding [java code](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/Quick.java.html).

#### #2

You already shuffle the array in `quicksort`, no need to shuffle it again and again in `partition`!

Also, note that your `shuffle` method shuffles the whole array, independently from `j`, `low` and `high`.

Shuffling only the left and right subarrays separately at each iteration would work, even though it would be unneeded.

#### #3

`quicksort` should return `arr`.

## Complete code

```
def shuffle(arr)
  arr.each_index do |i|
    r = rand(0..i)
    arr[i], arr[r] = arr[r], arr[i]
  end
  arr
end

def partition!(arr,low, high)
  i = low + 1 
  j = high
  while true 
    until arr[i] >= arr[low]
      break if i >= high
      i+=1
    end

    until arr[j] <= arr[low]
      j-=1
    end

    if i>=j 
      #done 
      arr[j], arr[low] = arr[low], arr[j]
      break 
    else 
      #swap and continue
      arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    end
  end 
  j
end


def quicksort(arr, low = 0, high=arr.length-1)
  arr = shuffle(arr)
  quicksort!(arr, low, high)
  arr
end

def quicksort!(arr, low, high)
   return arr if (high <= low)
   j = partition!(arr, low, high)
   quicksort!(arr, low, j-1)
   quicksort!(arr, j+1, high)
end

arr = [3,2,1,4,5]
p quicksort(arr)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. I don't fully understand why shuffling twice is a bad thing. For example, if I have my original array partitioned at j, then everything to the left is smaller and everything to the right is smaller. Within each half, however, there is no order.

So-- when I jumble up the left half of the array (0..j-1) and partition it, why does it matter that it was shuffled again? The only relevance the left half has is its order with respect to arr[j]..right?